# FB Sign in no longer using local ACAccount (New Facebook SDK API v2.2)

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

So the last Facebook SDK did the following

Using `FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions`

1. If user has a Facebook ACAccount, it'd use this to log in. Usually with a UIAlertView saying ''This App' would like to access your Basic Information and List of Friends'
2. Attempt Log in using the Native FB app
3. Attempt Log in using Facebook in safari

The new SDK no longer presents 1. and only gives options for 2. and 3. 
am I doing something wrong? Or is this just the way now?